# Bounded parameterized types with typed/racket

Tags: generics, bounded-wildcard, typed-racket

Let's say I have a function operating on values of type `base` and returning values of type `base`:

```
(struct base ([x : Real]))
(struct child base ([y : String]))

(: fun (base base → base))
(define (fun a b)
  (if (> (base-x a) (base-x b))
      a
      b))
```

The function `fun` can also be restricted to the type `child`, in which case it is guaranteed to return values of type `child` (without modifying the code):

```
(: fun (child child → child))
```

One can also make it accept `base` or `child` values, and return the same type:

```
(: fun (case→ (base base → base)
              (child child → child)))
```

This lacks the bound, and fails for obvious reasons:

```
(: fun (All (T) (T T → T)))
```

**How can I simplify this when there are many `child` types, by providing a bound to `All`?**

I'm looking for some syntax similar to this one:

```
(: fun (All (T : base) (T T → T)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not supported directly, but in the [latest snapshot versions](https://pre.racket-lang.org/installers/), it's possible to simulate that with [intersection types](https://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/snapshots/current/doc/ts-reference/type-ref.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types-extra..rkt%29._~e2~88~a9%29%29):

```
(: fun : (All (T) ((∩ base T) (∩ base T) → (∩ base T))))
```

Then `fun` returns the most specific type it can when given mixes of `base` and `child` types:

```
> (fun (base 1) (base 2))
- : base
#<base>
> (fun (base 1) (child 2 "string"))
- : base
#<child>
> (fun (child 1 "string") (base 2))
- : base
#<base>
> (fun (child 1 "string") (child 2 "string"))
- : (∩ child base)
#<child>
> (ann (fun (child 1 "string") (child 2 "string")) child)
- : child
#<child>
```

And you can use a `(∩ child base)` in a context that expects a `child`.